# Battleship Project Problems

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

```
    public class Basic
{
    public static int numGuess;
    public int guess;
    public int numHits = 0;
    private static int[] ships;
    private boolean hitShip;
    public static boolean shipSunk;
    private int[]board = new int[5];
    public Basic()
    {
        numGuess = 0;
        hitShip = false;
        shipSunk = false;
    }

        public static void setShips (int[] loc)
    {
        ships = loc;
    }

    public int Check(int z)
    {
        for(int cell : ships)
        {
            if(z == cell)
            {
                hitShip = true;
                System.out.println("\nYou hit an enemy ship!");
                numHits++;
                numGuess++;
                if(numHits == ships.length)
                {
                    shipSunk = true;
                    System.out.println("\nYou sunk the enemy ship!");
                    System.out.println("the number of guesses it took you to sink the ship is " + numGuess/3);
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You've missed the enemy ship!");
            }
        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

So I've been working on this battleship project for school and i made this 1-D board for my game. So far i think I've got my code correct, but now i'm stuck. In my for each loop, since it checks my guess with each of the three values of my ship, it prints whether or not i hit the ship three different times everytime i guess. I'm trying to get my program just to print whether or not i hit the ship once everytime i guess.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class BasicTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Basic shipp = new Basic(); //initalizes basic class
        int ship = (int)(Math.random() * 5); // gives ship a random # between 1 - 5
        int ship1;
        int ship2;
        int guess;
        if(ship <= 2)
        {
            ship1 = ship + 1;
            ship2 = ship + 2;
        }
        else
        {
            ship1 = ship - 1;
            ship2 = ship - 2;
        }
        int[] locations = {ship, ship1, ship2};// sets array of locations
        shipp.setShips(locations); // sets locations to ships in other class
        Scanner guesss = new Scanner(System.in);  // Scanner
        do
        {
            System.out.println("\nTell me where the enemy ship is.");
            guess = guesss.nextInt(); // gives guess the int from Scanner
            int resultb = shipp.Check(guess); // puts the int guess through the check method
        }
        while(Basic.shipSunk == false);
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you stuck? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your

```
else
        {
            System.out.println("You've missed the enemy ship!");
        }
```

Inside the loop, you should set a flag before the loop

```
hitIt = false;
```

Then, when you check against the three "ships", you can set this flag to "true" when you find a hit.  Finally, check the flag after the loop. If it is still false, print your message.